# How to print double or float number without losing precision?

Tags: double, precision

When I want to output a double (or float) number, such as `4.999999999999999999999`, which is over the double precision (15 digits), the result of double is `5.000000000000000` and the result of float is `5.000000`.

How can I print the original number without losing precision?

Comment: sorry, it is 15digits,

Comment: use `long double`. it should be larger(or atleast the same size) than double.

Comment: If you want arbitrary precision you could try using GMP (http://gmplib.org/). It is a library for arbitrary precision maths

Comment: thank you for your answer, long double doesn't work, the GMP is a good lib, I will try!